# Approximation for the following integral needed

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation, approximation-theory

I have following integral $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax-bx^m}dx$$ where $a>0, b>0, m>1$. I can get an approximation for the above integral when $b$ is small. However, I want to get an expression for the case when $b$ is large. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you do a u-substitution to get to the case of $b$ small.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am not interested in the case when $b$ is small. I am interested in the case when $b$ is not small.

Comment: You said you know what to do when $b$ is small. I'm saying, if $b$ is large, then do a u-substitution to get $b$ to be small, and then apply the approximation you know holds.

Comment: @mathworker21 means $x=s^{-1}u$ where $s$ is very large value. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @mathworker21 this seems pretty simple and straightforward but the problem is that it will result in same answer as if have not performed the u-substitution. Please note that for small $b$ case I am using $e^{-bx^m}\simeq 1-bx^{m}$. Now you can see that even with the u-substitution the answer will not change. That means the accuracy with the u-substitution and without it will remain same.

Comment: By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality such integral is bounded by $$\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)}{2a(2b)^{1/m}}}$$ for any $a,b>0$, but such bound is pretty loose if $m$ is large.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you for your comment. For how large $m$? Further is it a lower bound or an upper bound?

Comment: @FrankMoses: it is an upper bound, and a loose one if $m\geq 10$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio hmmm. Can we get a lower bound too?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am interested in values of $m\leq 3$

Comment: @FrankMoses: in such a case it is pretty accurate, and a lower bound can be designed by applying a step of integration by parts, then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you please add some steps in deriving the lower bound using Cauchy Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the factor $e^{-ax}$ in series and integrating term-by-term yields

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^m} e^{-ax}\,dx = \frac{b^{-1/m}}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-a)^k \operatorname{\Gamma}\!\left(\frac{k+1}{m}\right)}{k!} b^{-k/m}.
$$

This series also serves as an asymptotic series as $b \to +\infty$.

Comment: Why asymptotic? Does it not converge?

Comment: @YuriyS it converges *and* is an [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion#Formal_definition).

Comment: Thank you for clarification